# Other method is not working after calling first method

Tags: flutter, audio, provider, just-audio

In my flutter application I'm fetching music from url. I have save the url into provider but don't know why it is not playing after hitting onPress button. Here I'm sure that in provider, url of the music is available. the exact problem is that if I will press the list to play specific audio then a method called *audioInit()* is being called and url of the music will be set as audio source in music palyer lib. after that when press play button then it is not playing the music or pausing the music. I have used *just_audio* third part library to manage music stuff.

Below of code of that provider where I'm setting url:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class StoryManageState extends ChangeNotifier {

  String _currentStoryName = "";
  String _currentStoryPoster = "";
  String _currentEpisodeName = "";
  String _currentEpisodeLink = "";

  String get currentStoryName => _currentStoryName;
  String get currentStoryPoster => _currentStoryPoster;
  String get currentEpisodeName => _currentEpisodeName;
  String get currentEpisodeLink => _currentEpisodeLink;

  void setCurrentStoryName(String story) {
    _currentStoryName = story;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCurrentStoryPoster(String storyPoster) {
    _currentStoryPoster = storyPoster;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCurrentEpisodeName(String episodeName) {
    _currentEpisodeName = episodeName;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCurrentEpisodeLink(String episodeLink) {
    _currentEpisodeLink = episodeLink;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

below is the code where I'm giving music url to audio player:

```
import 'package:app/model/story_manage_state.dart';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../model/player_state.dart';
import '../widgets/choice_widget.dart';

class StoryAudioService {

  // final BuildContext context;

  // AudioService(this.context);
  //
  // factory AudioService.fromContext(BuildContext context) {
  //   return AudioService(context);
  // }

  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  Future<void> audioInit(BuildContext context) async {

    final playerStateModel = Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context,listen: false);
    final storyManageState = Provider.of<StoryManageState>(context, listen: false);

    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());

    audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((position) {
      playerStateModel.setDurationValue(position.inSeconds.toDouble());
      Duration duration = Duration(seconds: playerStateModel.currentDurationValue.toInt());
      playerStateModel.setCurrentPosition(duration);
    });

    audioPlayer.durationStream.listen((event) {
      playerStateModel.setDuration(event!);
    });

    audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) {
      if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed && !playerStateModel.isCompleted) {
        playerStateModel.setIsPlaying(false);
        playerStateModel.setIsCompleted(true);
        playerStateModel.setBeginToPlay(false);
        Choice().showChoices(context);
      } else if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.ready) {
        playerStateModel.setIsCompleted(false);
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("_-_-_-_-_-_ SONG NOT COMPLETED _-_-_-_-_-_");
        }
      }
    });

    audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('A stream error occurred: $e');
      }
    });

    try {
      // AAC example: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.aac
      // print("_-_-_-_-_-_ EPISODE LINK _-_-_-_-_-_ ${storyManageState.currentEpisodeLink}");
      await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(storyManageState.currentEpisodeLink),
        tag: MediaItem(
          // Specify a unique ID for each media item:
          id: 'StoryFy',
          // Metadata to display in the notification:
          album: storyManageState.currentStoryName,
          title: storyManageState.currentEpisodeName,
          artUri: Uri.parse(storyManageState.currentStoryPoster),
        ),
      ))
      //     .then((value) {
      //   playerStateModel.setIsPlaying(true);
      //   audioPlayer.play();
      // })
      ;

      // final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
      playerStateModel.setCurrentPosition(audioPlayer.duration!);
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Error loading audio source: $e");
      }
    }
  }

  String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    final hours = duration.inHours.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final seconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$hours:$minutes:$seconds';
  }

  playMusic(context) {
    print("_-_-_-_-_-_ PLAY MUSIC CALLED _-_-_-_-_-_ \t${Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).isPlaying}");
    if (Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).isPlaying) {
      audioPlayer.play();
    }
  }

  pauseMusic(context) {
    print("_-_-_-_-_-_ PAUSE MUSIC CALLED _-_-_-_-_-_ \t${Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).isPlaying}");
    // if (Provider.of<PlayerStateModel>(context, listen: false).isPlaying == false) {
      audioPlayer.pause();
    // }
  }

  void seekSlider(duration) {
    audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: duration));
  }

  void playPrevious() {
    audioPlayer.seekToPrevious();
  }

  void playNext() {
    audioPlayer.seekToNext();
  }

  void replay10() {
    if (audioPlayer.duration != null) {
      final newPosition = audioPlayer.position - const Duration(seconds: 10);
      final clampedPosition = newPosition.isNegative ? Duration.zero : newPosition;
      audioPlayer.seek(clampedPosition);
    }
  }

  void forward10() {
    final duration = audioPlayer.duration;
    if (duration != null) {
      final newPosition = audioPlayer.position + const Duration(seconds: 10);
      final clampedPosition = newPosition.compareTo(duration) > 0 ? duration : newPosition;
      audioPlayer.seek(clampedPosition);
    }
  }

}
```

below is the code for onPress of IconButton:

```
Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
                  builder: (context, playerStateModel, child) {
                    return IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (mounted == true) {
                          // playerStateModel
                          //     .setIsPlaying(!playerStateModel.isPlaying);
                          setState(() {
                            playerStateModel.setIsPlaying(!playerStateModel.isPlaying);
                            (playerStateModel.isPlaying)
                                ? audioService.playMusic(context)
                                : audioService.pauseMusic(context);
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      iconSize: height * 0.05,
                      color: Colors.storyfytheme,
                      icon: playerStateModel.isPlaying
                          ? const Icon(
                        Icons.pause,
                      )
                          : const Icon(
                        Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
```

## UPDATE

So far I have observed that when I use `_.then()_` method then music is playing good but still can not pause, forward for backward when music is playing. I can say that after execution of `audioInit()` method all other method *( playMusic(), pauseMusic(), seekSlider(), playPrevious(), playNext(), replay10(), forward10() )* are being called but can not able to perform defined operations.